# Sonatype Nexus Rest API 401 Unauthorzed

Tags: rest, repository, nexus, sonatype

I'm trying to get an artifact from a secured nexus repository from java using the Rest API. I'm getting 401 Unauthorized as a response.

What do I need to do in order to authorize myself?

```
String url = "http://myNexus.com/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=my-repo&g=my.group&a=my-artifact&v=LATEST";

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

HttpResponse response = null;

response = client.execute(request);

System.out.println("Response Code : "
       + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the Nexus Client library rather than writing your own Java wrapper for the REST API. More details and links to examples are [in the Nexus book.](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-plugins.html)

Comment: The whole point of REST is that you’re independent of libraries and specific languages and runtimes.

Comment: That of course is true. However the URL was never designed as a REST API and does not adhere to any REST ideas.

Comment: The title of this question explicitly mentions “REST API” and Sonatype [documents it as REST API as well](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api). So I don’t see how you can say the URL was never designed as or adheres to a REST API.

Comment: That does not change the fact that it is not a REST API in the traditional sense..also the link you are providing is for Nexus 3 which is a totally separate and different application .. and it does have a REST API..

Answer (score 0):

I used java to simulate GET method. The 3rd param "auth" is the basic http authentication example.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASE64

```
    public String sendGet(String url, String param, String auth) {
    String result = "";
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        String urlName = url + "?" + param;
        URL realUrl = new URL(urlName);
        URLConnection conn = realUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("accept", "*/*");
        conn.setRequestProperty("connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("user-agent",
                "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + auth);
        conn.connect();
        in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```